# Make html post form auto return after submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a simple form on `contact.html` which posts to `send.php` with post and mail headers on, but it just `stays on send.php` `after submit`.

How can i get this to `return back to contact.html`. Can this be done within the php block on send.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
<?php

// your other code here

header('Location: /contact.html');
exit;
?>
```

Make sure there is nothing output before that code or you will get an error.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this before but indent spacing must have took it off. why is this?

Comment: The documentation (link above) states: Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP file, after all the form processing, use this:

```
header("Location: contact.html");
```

The only requirement is that there is no output (including empty lines) before this function.